# How can I boot into an existing archlinux arm installation using Qemu?

Tags: archlinux, qemu

I have flashed archlinux arm to my raspberry pi's SD card, and installed some packages.  I have also created a non-privileged user account.

I would now like to plug the SD card into my x86_64 computer using a USB microcontroller, and boot the arch install using qemu.

**Note** this is *not* the same question as, "how do I boot an archlinux arm image using Qemu?".

`dmesg` reports:

```
[858076.937323] sd 14:0:0:1: [sdf] Assuming drive cache: write through
[858076.938569]  sdf: sdf1 sdf2 sdf3
```

where partitions `sdf{1,2,3}` correspond--respectively--to boot, root, and home mountpoints.

`fstab` on the pi is:

```
/dev/root               /       auto defaults                       0 1
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults        0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p3  /home       ext4    defaults,user        0       0
```

I have tried a bunch of different qemu incantations, such as:

```
sudo qemu-system-arm -machine versatilepb \
                     -cpu arm1176 -m 1024 -no-reboot -serial stdio \
                     -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rw" -hda /dev/sdf \
                     -kernel /mnt/rpi/boot/kernel.img
```

But I'm getting a black screen when I run the above command.

Finally, I'd like to add the tag "qemu" but don't have the rep...

**EDIT** @Jivings:

Getting warmer, but I'm unable to unpack the `kernel.img` as it doesn't seem to be in a standard format.  I found some interesting information on Github, however, regarding how that `kernel.img` file is created:

This step of the build script:

https://github.com/archlinuxarm/PKGBUILDs/blob/master/core/linux-raspberrypi/PKGBUILD#L111

Calls this python script, which concatenates two files into `kernel.img`:

https://github.com/archlinuxarm/PKGBUILDs/blob/master/core/linux-raspberrypi/imagetool-uncompressed.py

See also:

https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools/issues/2

```
% sudo mount -o loop,offset=32768 kernel.img /mnt/kernel
```

does not work.

Actually I think that the output of

```
dd bs=$(stat -c%s first32k.bin) skip=1 if=kernel.img
```

would be `bzImage` ... correct?

Comment: Unfortunately you need the kernel image (`zImage`) which I think is found inside `kernel.img`. Can you extract or mount that and see?

Comment: Please see my note above.

Comment: I want to do the same. Do you have made any progress on your question?